# H3 css issue on IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

Custom design for `<h3>` tag... it work nicely on IE8, Firefox and Chrome.

But on IE7, the width (100%) is full which it shouldn't happen.  How to fix this?

Also the font size don't appear to be the same as IE8, Firefox and Chrome

```
h3 {
    background-color:white;
    display:inline-block;
    color:black;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-top:6px;
    padding-bottom:6px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
h3 {
    display:inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;

    background-color:white;
    color:black;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-top:6px;
    padding-bottom:6px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
 }
```

`*display: inline` uses a ["safe CSS hack"](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/safe-css-hacks) to target only IE7. `zoom: 1` provides [hasLayout](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html) for IE7 and lower, which is required to make this work.

To fix the font size, specify an explicit `font-size`. For example `font-size: 24px`.

Answer (score 2):

IE7 simply doesn't support `display: inline-block` on elements that aren't natively inline. You could fix it by setting `display: inline` and using various positioning things to make it work, or, alternatively, use an IE-specific stylesheet using conditional comments that sets the width manually.

It depends on your layout.

Comment: there is a simple hack hor this, so why not use it?

Comment: @gar_onn: Because it's a hack. Standards-compliant browsers shouldn't need to waste time downloading and parsing hacks. It might not matter though, as `display: inline` could be sufficient for this case and would work in every browser - maybe even without adjustment! And that's always nice.

Comment: @minitech: That not really a reason not to (use the method in my answer), it is? `*display: inline` is irrelevant in both download and "parsing" time. `display: inline` won't work here because he's adding `margin` and `padding`.

Comment: @thirtydot: But that's exactly why it depends on the layout. See: http://jsfiddle.net/y5ayP/ Padding and margin *work*, just not quite in the same way (no, vertical margins don't work. But the background color is white. So it depends on the layout).

Answer (score 1):

IE 7 does not support: inline-block

but you can 'hack' it by adding this to the end

```
zoom:1;
*display: inline;
```

hack found at: http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/

Comment: It supports `inline-block` for elements which are normally inline, such as `span`.